# How to find the file path of file that is not the current file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a folder full of files, some are txt files and others are rb files. What I would like to do is find the path of one of those txt files using the code in the `main.rb` file.

I suppose a cheap trick would be to use `File.dirname(__FILE__)` which would get the path of the current rb file and since the txt file is in the same folder it works. but God forbid the txt file was not in the same folder, is there a way to still locate the path to that txt file?

Comment: so possibilly you don't know the path and neither the relative position to the map of your script ? but you do know the name ? you are looking for a file search solution ? for what OS ?

Comment: yeah that's pretty much the situation, the OS would be windows

Comment: I am interested in knowing how this could be done by shelling out to the operating system. Anyone care to offer an answer along those lines?

Comment: @Cary I added a method that uses a shell, when you need extra info such as last modified time you indeed need that, but using the tool I suggested (ES) shells out too, but I suppose you mean using only the commands available in the default shelll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `Dir['c:/**/test.txt']` will give you an array of all the test.txt files on your c: drive.

`Dir['c:/**/*.txt']` will give you all files with the .txt extension (could be a lot)

But in windows there is the exellent tool [search everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), it also has a command line version whose output you can capture in a Ruby script. On a large folder or drive this is going to be a lot faster that "Dir" or "Find" which can also be used. I once did that, here the method that does that, you will need to install both everything and the command line extension.

```
require 'win32ole'
ES = 'C:\****\es\es.exe' # path to command line of Search Everything

def filelist path
  command = %Q{"#{ES}" -n 60 folder: -p #{path.join(" ").gsub('/','\\')}}
  list = []
  IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |pipe|
    while lijn = pipe.gets
      list << lijn.chomp
    end
  end
  list.join(',')
end
```

EDIT

For Gary, a methods that shells out to the OS, I use this in a Sync tool of me that needs the last modified time of a file and getting that with the Ruby methods is way too slow for more than a thousand files.
It returns a hash which key is the path and the value is the last modified date of the file. It skips some filesAdapt as you wish.

```
def list_files path
    folder, collection = "", {}
    IO.popen("dir /s /a:-d #{path}\\*.* 2>&1").each_line do |line|
      case line
        when /$RECYCLE.BIN|AlbumArt/ # skip these
        when /\d{8}T\d{6}/ # skip these
        when /desktop.ini|thumbs.db|sync_hist$/ # skip these
        when /^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}  \d{2}:\d{2})/
          modified = $1
          filename = line[36..-1].chomp
          collection["#{folder}\\#{filename}".downcase] = DateTime::strptime(modified, "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M") rescue nil
        when /^ Map van / # Dutch for Folder of (my OS is in Dutch)
          folder = line[9..-1].chomp[path.length..-1]
      end
    end
    collection
  end
```

EDIT2

Today I had to use one of those methods because my folder I had to process contained some 30000 files and the waittime before something happened with the normal Ruby Dir was just too long and my system froze while the script executed.

I remembered this answer so I thought to include the results.

I did some benchmarks and the clear winner is de dir from windows self.
There were some errors and extras in the methods I first published but I'm not going to change them because the answer was acceptedl like that and the extra (eg modified time) could be usefull.

In stead here the three ways I tested with their benchmarks and a fourth using lazy to see what changes (not much).

```
require 'benchmark' 

STDOUT.sync = true
start_folder = 'c:/jpg'

def ruby_dir folder
  ruby_folder = folder.gsub('\\','/')
  files = []
  Dir.glob("#{ruby_folder}/**/*").each do |file|
    files << file if File.file? file
  end
  files
end

def ruby_dir_with_lazy folder
  ruby_folder = folder.gsub('\\','/')
  files = []
  Dir.glob("#{ruby_folder}/**/*").lazy.each do |file|
    if File.file? file
      files << file
    end
  end
  files
end

def os_dir path
  win_path = path.gsub('/','\\')
  files = []
  folder = win_path
  IO.popen("dir /s /a:-d #{win_path}\\*.* 2>&1").each_line do |line|
    case line
      when /^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}  \d{2}:\d{2})/
        filename = line[36..-1].chomp
        files << "#{folder}\\#{filename}"
      when /^ Map van / # Dutch for Folder of (my OS is in Dutch)
        folder = line[9..-1].chomp
    end
  end
  files
end

def es_dir path
  win_path = path.gsub('/','\\')
  files = []
  es = 'c:\everything\es\es.exe' # path to command line of Search Everything
  command = %Q{"#{es}" -p #{win_path}}
  IO.popen(command+" 2>&1").each_line do |line|
    files << line
  end
  files
end

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report("ruby_dir          ") { 3.times { ruby_dir(path) } }
  x.report("ruby_dir_with_lazy") { 3.times { ruby_dir_with_lazy(path) } }
  x.report("os_dir            ") { 3.times { os_dir(path) } } 
  x.report("es_dir            ") { 3.times { es_dir(path) } } 
end
```

os_dir gives a 26 times as fast result as the standard Ruby Dir

```
ruby_dir            1.747000  18.626000  20.373000 ( 20.397883)
ruby_dir_with_lazy  1.482000  18.799000  20.281000 ( 20.340853)
os_dir              0.608000   0.124000   0.732000 (  0.786640)
es_dir              1.202000   1.202000   2.404000 (  5.905093)
```

Comment: thanks peter, but i don't think you have to search for it, the `Dir['c:/**/test.txt']` is perfect for all i need to do.

Comment: How do you know the file is on `C:` if you don't know where it is?

Comment: @Jorg if you don't you will have to enumerate alle drives and the solution would be OS dependent (and even slower) also iaa, in that case a reason more to use SE which has no problem with that

Comment: Speaking for both Gary and me, thanks for addendum where you shell out to the OS.